# How to know email of a Gmail chat contact?

Tags: gmail, google-contacts

I have some contacts in Gmail chat that I don't know its email. And in some other I have the option to send them an email, why is that? Is there a way to see the contact email?

**Contact with email:**

[image]

**Contact without email:**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There are several factors at play here:

- If you have a contact’s email in your address book, then you’re able to send them an email through Gmail Chat.
- It is also possible that if you added someone on Google+ by searching for them by email address, that information might become available in your address book and thus in Chat.
- There is a Gmail setting that lets you select who can send send you an email via Google+. Your second contact must have set that preference to `No One` (assuming you are in their Circles as well).

[image: Google+ Email]